Trouble with understanding 待たせる
I have trouble understanding the 待たせて in this lyrics:
まだ朝はたっぷりあるからあと５分いや１０分待たせて (from おちゃめ機能)
Is it saying that the speaker is waiting? or that someone else is waiting?
Because I think one would normally use 待って for other the other person.

I agree that one would normally use 待って, which means “please wait 10 more minutes for me to get up” in presence of others, but 待たせる also makes sense if we interpret it as “let me wait 10 more minutes until I finally (come to terms with the end of my dream and accept to) wake up”.
